# Computing & Evaluating Negative Time Values in VBA

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and have encountered an issue.
My objective is to find an elegant way of evaluating negative time values.

For example, the body of code below generates a message box which displays `12:30:00 AM`. I would expect it to display `11:30:00 PM`.

```
Sub Main() 'Run Test
Dim difference As Date
    difference = #12:00:00 AM# - #12:30:00 AM#
    MsgBox difference
End Sub
```

I have created a solution to this issue, but would like to know the coding community's feedback.
Some of the code is not necessary, but I have written it for functionality that may be important in the future.

The `run` sub routine allows you to run the `test` function with your specified values.
The `test` function tests the `timeDiff` & `timeSum` logic.
The `timeDiff` function finds the time-difference between `t1` and `t0`.
The `timeSum` function finds the time-sum of `t1` and `t0`.
The `asDuration` function removes the AM/PM suffix from a time value.
The `asMilitary` function converts 12-hour format to 24 hour-format.
The `concat` function I created to more easily concatenate strings.

```
Sub Main() 'Run Test
    MsgBox Test("0:29:0", "23:30:0")
End Sub


Function Test(startT As Date, endT As Date) 'Test timeDiff & timeSum logic
    Dim nextShift As Date, prevShift As Date, hours As Date

    hours = timeDiff(endT, startT)
    prevShift = timeDiff(startT, "0:30:0")
    nextShift = timeSum("0:30:0", endT)        

    Test = concat("Start -", startT, "", "End - ", endT, "", "Duration -", asDuration(hours), "", "Next Shift: ", nextShift, "", "Prev Shift: ", prevShift)
End Function


Function timeDiff(t1 As Date, t0 As Date) As Date 'Return Time1 minus Time0
    Dim units(0 To 2) As String

    units(0) = Hour(t1) - Hour(t0)
    units(1) = Minute(t1) - Minute(t0)
    units(2) = Second(t1) - Second(t0)

    If units(2) < 0 Then
        units(2) = units(2) + 60
        units(1) = units(1) - 1
    End If

    If units(1) < 0 Then
        units(1) = units(1) + 60
        units(0) = units(0) - 1
    End If

    units(0) = IIf(units(0) < 0, units(0) + 24, units(0))
    timeDiff = Join(units, ":")
End Function


Function timeSum(t1 As Date, t0 As Date) As Date 'Return Time1 plus Time0
    Dim units(0 To 2) As String

    units(0) = Hour(t1) + Hour(t0)
    units(1) = Minute(t1) + Minute(t0)
    units(2) = Second(t1) + Second(t0)

    If units(2) >= 60 Then
        units(2) = units(2) Mod 60
        units(1) = units(1) + 1
    End If

    If units(1) >= 60 Then
        units(1) = units(1) Mod 60
        units(0) = units(0) + 1
    End If

    units(0) = IIf(units(0) >= 24, units(0) Mod 24, units(0))
    timeSum = Join(units, ":")
End Function


Function asDuration(time As Date) As String 'Display as duration; Remove AM/PM suffix from time
    time = asMilitary(time)
    asDuration = Left(time, Len(time))
End Function


Function asMilitary(time As Date) As String 'Convert 12-hour format to 24-hour-format
    asMilitary = Hour(time) & ":" & Minute(time) & ":" & Second(time)
End Function


Function concat(ParamArray var() As Variant) As String 'Return arguments of function call concatenated as a single string
    For Each elem In var()
        concat = IIf(elem <> "", concat & elem & " ", concat & vbNewLine)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Were you working this as an exercise? Most of what you've done is already available in [library functions in VBA](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php).

Comment: How do you compute & evaluate negative time values?  
  
For example, the body of code below generates a message box which displays `12:30:00 AM`. I would expect it to display `11:30:00 PM`.  

`Sub Main() 'Run Test`
`Dim difference As Date`
`difference = #12:00:00 AM# - #12:30:00 AM#`
`MsgBox difference`
`End Sub`

The only solution I have found for computing such a value is by creating the `timeDiff` function mentioned above.  
Could you describe a way to subtract 30 minutes from 12:00:00 AM and get an output of 11:30:00 PM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a bit trickier than my initial tests. Just typing into the immediate window of the VBA Editor allowed me to work several items by hand that the Editor "intelligently corrected" for me. But the underlying solution remains the same in any case.

The key is to "anchor" your time value on a date -- any date will do because it will be subtracted away later. But this makes your math work out as expected.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Debug.Print TimeDiff("12:00:00", "00:30:00")
    Debug.Print TimeDiff("0:29:0", "23:30:0")
    Debug.Print TimeDiff("16:00:00", "4:30:00")
End Sub

Function TimeDiff(t1 As Date, t0 As Date) As Date
    '--- returns t1-t0

    Dim d1 As Date
    Dim dayAnchor As Date

    dayAnchor = #1/1/2015#
    d1 = dayAnchor + t1
    TimeDiff = (d1 - t0) - dayAnchor
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Sub Main() 'Run Test
    MsgBox Test("00:29:00", "23:30:00")
End Sub

Function Test(startT As Date, endT As Date) 'Test timeDiff logic
    Dim nextShift As Date, prevShift As Date, hours As Date

    hours = timeDiff(endT, startT)
    prevShift = timeDiff(startT, "0:30:0")
    nextShift = timeDiff("0:30:0", endT)

    Test = concat("Start -", startT, "", "End - ", endT, "", "Duration -", asDuration(hours), "", "Next Shift: ", nextShift, "", "Prev Shift: ", prevShift)
End Function


Function timeDiff(t1 As Date, t0 As Date) As Date 'Returns t1-t0
    dayAnchor = #1/1/2015#
    timeDiff = ((dayAnchor + TimeValue(t1)) - TimeValue(t0)) - dayAnchor
End Function

Function asDuration(time As Date) As String 'Display as duration; Remove AM/PM suffix from time
    t = Hour(time) & ":" & Minute(time) & ":" & Second(time)
    asDuration = Left(t, Len(t))
End Function

Function concat(ParamArray var() As Variant) As String 'Return arguments of function call concatenated as a single string
    For Each elem In var()
        concat = IIf(elem <> "", concat & elem & " ", concat & vbNewLine)
    Next
End Function
```